# Apache Redirect with OR Operator

Tags: apache-2.2, .htaccess, redirect, 301-redirect

How can I use the Apache OR operator to redirect several paths to one URL? E.g.:

```
RewriteEngine on
RedirectMatch   301 /foo || /foo/bar || /das.html https://example.com/ext/ddy/$1
```

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 1):

```
RedirectMatch 301 ^(/foo|/foo/bar|/das.html)$ https://example.com/ext/ddy/$1
```

You can learn about this in the docs for [Perl-Compatible Regular Expressions (PCRE)](http://www.pcre.org/current/doc/html/pcre2syntax.html), which Apache uses.